# Sending funds from one contract to another contract

Tags: solidity

I was just wondering with the below code between the highlighted part ** - why could the line not be re-written as `ContractOne one = _contractOne;` ?

````
    mapping(address => uint) public addressBalances;

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        addressBalances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}

contract ContractTwo {

    function deposit() public payable {}

    function depositOnContractOne(address _contractOne) public { 
        ContractOne one = ContractOne(_contractOne);
        one.deposit{value: 10, gas: 100000}(); 
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is not how you declare new contract instance. What you are doing there is simply creating new **contractone** instance with the new keyword.

It goes like this,  `<contractname> <newInstanceName> = new <contractname(constructor parameters)`

So your code should be:

```
contract ContractTwo {

    function deposit() public payable {}

    function depositOnContractOne(address _contractOne) public { 
        ContractOne one = new ContractOne(_contractOne);
        one.deposit{value: 10, gas: 100000}(); 
    }
}
```

As far your question, if you have ever OOPs program paradigm, you should've come across new object instantiation to use it without affecting the original class. It is similar to this.

However, you are using contract as datatype in this case. It is common factory contract practice.

You can read more about new keyword [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/control-structures.html?highlight=new%20keyword#creating-contracts-via-new:%7E:text=%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Creating%20Contracts%20via,-new).

And [here](https://cryptomarketpool.com/new-keyword-in-solidity-smart-contracts/).

Tell me if it helps!